# Python error inside worker for map_async effects execution plan

Tags: python, error-handling, multiprocessing

folks! I've faced this issue and I'm curious about what's going on.
The Pool forks 3 processes. My further assumptions: each process will pull tasks from the parent task queue. As we see process didn't die but some of the tasks are skipped. Maybe anyone has ideas?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


def wrk(a):
    if a % 3 == 0:
        print(a, os.getpid(), 'GONNA DIE')
        raise ValueError('ERROR')
    else:
        print(a, os.getpid())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        p = pool.map_async(wrk, (i for i in range(50)))
        p.wait()
```

results

```
0 29836 GONNA DIE
5 29835
6 29835 GONNA DIE
10 29836
11 29836
12 29836 GONNA DIE
15 29836 GONNA DIE
20 29836
21 29836 GONNA DIE
25 29835
26 29835
27 29835 GONNA DIE
30 29836 GONNA DIE
35 29835
36 29835 GONNA DIE
40 29836
41 29836
42 29836 GONNA DIE
45 29835 GONNA DIE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting. When you do not specify the *chunksize* argument to the `map` method, a value is computed based on the size of the *iterable* and the pool size. In your case I believe it would use a *chunksize* value of 5.

This means that each idle process in the pool will pull up to 5 tasks from the input queue at a time and work on them as a batch. It seems (and this surprises me) that if one of those tasks raises an exception, the process does not go on to process any of the other remaining tasks in the batch. If we force the *chunksize* to 1, then we get:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


def wrk(a):
    if a % 3 == 0:
        print(a, os.getpid(), 'GONNA DIE')
        raise ValueError('ERROR')
    else:
        print(a, os.getpid())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        p = pool.map_async(wrk, (i for i in range(50)), chunksize=1)
        p.wait()
```

Prints:

```
0 186952 GONNA DIE
1 249800
2 249800
3 249800 GONNA DIE
4 186952
5 186952
6 244428 GONNA DIE
7 186952
8 186952
9 186952 GONNA DIE
10 249800
11 186952
12 249800 GONNA DIE
13 186952
14 186952
15 186952 GONNA DIE
16 249800
17 249800
18 249800 GONNA DIE
20 186952
19 244428
21 186952 GONNA DIE
22 244428
23 244428
24 249800 GONNA DIE
25 244428
26 186952
27 244428 GONNA DIE
28 186952
29 186952
30 249800 GONNA DIE
32 244428
31 186952
33 244428 GONNA DIE
34 186952
35 249800
36 186952 GONNA DIE
37 249800
38 244428
39 249800 GONNA DIE
40 244428
41 186952
42 244428 GONNA DIE
43 249800
44 186952
45 249800 GONNA DIE
46 186952
47 244428
48 249800 GONNA DIE
49 186952
```

Likewise, if we make the *chunksize=50*, so that the first idle process grabs all the submitted tasks, the only output is:

```
0 115408 GONNA DIE
```

The same thing occurs with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os


def wrk(a):
    if a % 3 == 0:
        print(a, os.getpid(), 'GONNA DIE')
        raise ValueError('ERROR')
    else:
        print(a, os.getpid())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        p = executor.map(wrk, (i for i in range(50)), chunksize=5)
```

Prints:

```
0 39280 GONNA DIE
5 60616
10 39280
6 60616 GONNA DIE
11 39280
12 39280 GONNA DIE
15 60616 GONNA DIE
20 39280
25 60616
21 39280 GONNA DIE
26 60616
30 39280 GONNA DIE
27 60616 GONNA DIE
35 104328
40 39280
45 60616 GONNA DIE
36 104328 GONNA DIE
41 39280
42 39280 GONNA DIE
```

But if you use the default *chunksize=1* value, you will see all 50 lines of output. So this "feature" is not peculiar to the `Pool` class.

Again, very surprising. I am going to take a look at the `multiprocessing` code and will try to get back to you on this.

**Update**

I looked at the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map` code, which was easier to follow than the code for `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map`, and sure enough once one of the tasks in the *chunksize* batch gets an exception, the rest of the tasks in the batch are abandoned.

If you are using `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` with a *chunksize* value > 1, then if an exception is raised in your worker function, not only is the rest of the batch abandoned, but any batches that are queued up and awaiting to be run. The `map` function itself will throw an exception. To get whatever results possible from successfully completed worker function executions, use `imap` (or `imap_unordered`.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(x):
    if x % 8 == 0:
        raise ValueError(str(x))
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(8)
    results = pool.imap(worker, range(1, 30), chunksize=4)
    it = results.__iter__()
    while True:
        try:
            x = it.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception:', e)
        else:
            print('x =', x)
```

Prints

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
Exception: 8
```

If, a *chunksize=1* argument is specified, then if the worker function raises an exception, queued up tasks waiting run or already running that haven't complete will not be abandoned:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(x):
    if x % 8 == 0:
        raise ValueError(str(x))
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(8)
    results = pool.imap(worker, range(1, 30), chunksize=1)
    it = results.__iter__()
    while True:
        try:
            x = it.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception:', e)
        else:
            print('x =', x)
```

Prints:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
Exception: 8
x = 9
x = 10
x = 11
x = 12
x = 13
x = 14
x = 15
Exception: 16
x = 17
x = 18
x = 19
x = 20
x = 21
x = 22
x = 23
Exception: 24
x = 25
x = 26
x = 27
x = 28
x = 29
```

The closest, equivalent program using `concurrent.futures` would be:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def worker(x):
    if x % 8 == 0:
        raise ValueError(str(x))
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    results = executor.map(worker, range(1, 30))
    it = results.__iter__()
    while True:
        try:
            x = it.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception:', e)
        else:
            print('x =', x)
```

(the default *chunksize* value used is 1)

Prints:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
Exception: 8
```

But, as you can see, once an exception is raised, all `map` processing stops as far as returning values is concerned. However, you can and should use the `submit` method instead to get around this problem:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def worker(x):
    if x % 8 == 0:
        raise ValueError(str(x))
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures = [executor.submit(worker, idx) for idx in range(1, 30)]
    for future in futures:
        try:
            x = future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception:', e)
        else:
            print('x =', x)
```

Prints:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
Exception: 8
x = 9
x = 10
x = 11
x = 12
x = 13
x = 14
x = 15
Exception: 16
x = 17
x = 18
x = 19
x = 20
x = 21
x = 22
x = 23
Exception: 24
x = 25
x = 26
x = 27
x = 28
x = 29
```

**Conclusion**

All these issues can be avoided if your worker function does not raise Exceptions. If it needs to return a value and an exceptional condition occurs, it could even return an `Exception` instance that the main process can test for:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(x):
    if x % 8 == 0:
        return ValueError(str(x))
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(8)
    results = pool.map(worker, range(1, 30), chunksize=4)
    for result in results:
        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            print('Exception:', result)
        else:
            print('x =', result)
```

Prints:

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
Exception: 8
x = 9
x = 10
x = 11
x = 12
x = 13
x = 14
x = 15
Exception: 16
x = 17
x = 18
x = 19
x = 20
x = 21
x = 22
x = 23
Exception: 24
x = 25
x = 26
x = 27
x = 28
x = 29
```

Comment: I didn't even expect such a great answer. Thank you!